How to solve a set of four differential equation?
I have the following set of differential equations:
\begin{align}
    \frac{d r_{00}(t)}{dt} &= -2 g r_{00}(t) - i \big( -h_{21}(t) r_{01}(t) + h_{12}(t) r_{10}(t) \big), \\
    \frac{d r_{01}(t)}{dt} &= -g r_{01}(t) - i \big( -h_{12}(t) r_{00}(t) + h_{11}(t) r_{01}(t) - h_{22}(t) r_{01}(t) + h_{12}(t) r_{11}(t) \big), \\
    \frac{d r_{10}(t)}{dt} &= -g r_{10}(t) - i \big( h_{21}(t) r_{00}(t) - h_{11}(t) r_{10}(t) + h_{22}(t) r_{10}(t) - h_{21}(t) r_{11}(t) \big), \\
    \frac{d r_{11}(t)}{dt} &= 2 g r_{00}(t) - i \big( h_{21}(t) r_{01}(t) - h_{12}(t) r_{10}(t) \big).
\end{align}
Here $g$ is real and time independent and coefficients $h_{ij}(t)$  are some arbitrary  finite real quantities. How can one solve such system? I am not familiar with solving coupled differential equations and would be thankful if someone provides with initial steps to proceed to the solution.

You have a system of the form $r’(t) = A(t) r(t)$.

Please notice the symmetry between eq. 1 and 4 and eqs. 2 and 3. I think the system would be simplified if you work with eqs $(1)\pm(4)$ and $(2)\pm(3)$ instead?
